# Change subsequent row values to previous maximum value up to that point if subsequent values are lower than the previous one. Ignore NA's

Tags: r

For example it looks like this now:

| Sample | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | NA | 2 | 1 | 3 |
| B | 1 | 2 | NA | 1 | 5 |
| C | 0 | 1 | 5 | NA | 3 |

I want it to look like this:

| Sample | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | NA | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| B | 1 | 2 | NA | 2 | 5 |
| C | 0 | 1 | 5 | NA | 5 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1 <- df
df1[is.na(df1)] <- -Inf
df1[-1] <- matrixStats::rowCummaxs(as.matrix(df1[-1]))* NA^is.na(df[-1])
df1
  Sample Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
1      A    1   NA    2    2    3
2      B    1    2   NA    2    5
3      C    0    1    5   NA    5
```

or even:

```
df1 <- df
df1[is.na(df1)] <- -Inf
df1[-1] <- matrixStats::rowCummaxs(as.matrix(df1[-1]))
is.na(df1) <- is.na(df)
df1
  Sample Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
1      A    1   NA    2    2    3
2      B    1    2   NA    2    5
3      C    0    1    5   NA    5
```

Answer (score 1):

We may use `cummax` from `base R` - loop over subset of dataset i.e. numeric columns(`[-1]`) by row with `apply` (`MARGIN = 1`), replace the non-NA elements with the cumulative max of the values and assign back

```
df[-1] <- t(apply(df[-1], 1, FUN = function(x) {
            i1 <- !is.na(x)
            x[i1] <- cummax(x[i1])
   x}))
```

-output

```
> df
  Sample Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
1      A    1   NA    2    2    3
2      B    1    2   NA    2    5
3      C    0    1    5   NA    5
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Sample = c("A", "B", "C"), Col1 = c(1L, 1L, 0L
), Col2 = c(NA, 2L, 1L), Col3 = c(2L, NA, 5L), Col4 = c(1L, 1L, 
NA), Col5 = c(3L, 5L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```